# Too much content white space on fixed layout

Tags: html, css, height, sticky-footer

I'm using a fixed header/footer layout with a .container and .content div in the middle of them but for some reason there is too much white space on the .container and its causing a scrollbar to appear when there is only 2 paragraphs of text in the `.content div.`

The fixed footer was working before i added the 100% header. I'm not entirely sure if my markup is bad and that is the reason or the "fixed footer" hack is conflicting with one of the classes.

**Live example :**  http://jsfiddle.net/A9vVX/7/embedded/result/

**Source :**
http://jsfiddle.net/A9vVX/7/

Does anyone know a solution to fix this, please fork it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i added a "height: auto;" to your .container

hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the height / scrollbar issue

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes

```
.header-wrap {
display: block;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
height: 200px;
background-color: #c8cfe9;
top: 0px;
}
.container {
min-height: 100%;
margin-bottom: -100px;
margin-top: 200px;
height: auto;
}
.footer {
background-color: #c8cfe9;
margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: I believe it adds a margin below the header/nav. I'm not sure if this is to do with the height of .container. Possibly the header is incorrect as i just added in a while ago, the fixed footer hack worked before that.

Answer (score 0):

I am setting your `.container` to have default `min-height` value which you can be tailored according to your needs. And the footer just stick below that.

Does this fiddle fix your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jofrysutanto/A9vVX/17/

Answer (score 0):

You should have `max-height:100%` to your container instead of `min-height:100%`.[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9vVX/18/)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand you correctly but i think you want something like this:

[image]

if yes here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lan="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
Home , MySite.com
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Head-Wrap">
<span id="Logo">
    <img src="logo.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="Logo" />
</span>
    <span class="header" >
    <ul class="Nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
    </ul>
    </span>
</div>   
<div class="container">


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus, tortor ac pulvinar eleifend, lectus velit scelerisque elit, vel mattis turpis tellus ut ante. Suspendisse pharetra ipsum blandit, condimentum purus pulvinar, facilisis nisl. Phasellus ac pulvinar nibh. Curabitur eu dolor eget enim ultricies fringilla et quis dui. Donec consequat vitae tortor in imperdiet. Ut eu posuere diam. Nunc tristique risus eget eros tempus, in adipiscing diam tincidunt. Phasellus eget erat felis..</p>


</div>
    <div id="footer">
        The Fixed Footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#Head-Wrap {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:white;
}
.header .Nav{
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
.header .Nav  li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 110px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.header .Nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.container {
background-color:white;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
top:350px;
position:fixed;
height:445px;
overflow:scroll;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    top:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:-101px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Fiddle:

FullScreen:

http://jsfiddle.net/a3Qsf/6/embedded/result/

Source:

http://jsfiddle.net/a3Qsf/6/

Download the HTML Source Doc:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw0i310f2bdmuv8/Stackoveflow.html

Test it in google chrome , Firefox , IE and on medium and high resolutions.